# Xcode UI Test Keyboard and MenuItems Buttons Broken

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I wrote some UI tests for Xcode that have been working for years. I tried running them again on Xcode 10.1 and iOS 12.1 and the same error is coming up in different parts of the code.

> "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "-[XCAXClient_iOS interruptingUIElementsAffectingSnapshot:] called with nil input, should have been prevented by nullability and call site checks."

I need to hide the keyboard, I was using the following code, but now I'm getting an error on the `tap()` call. Side note: using `typeText("\n")` is simulating the enter key being pressed, which I need to avoid.

```
if XCUIApplication().buttons["Hide keyboard"].exists {
    XCUIApplication().buttons["Hide keyboard"].tap()
}
```

I'm getting the same error trying to access certain `textField.menuItems`.The error also occurs on the `tap()` call. I was able to find a workaround for this one, but it would be nice to fix this as well.

```
let selectAllBtn = XCUIApplication().menuItems["Select All"]
selectAllBtn.tap()
```

The ideal solution would be to get the original code to work, but if that's not possible then any workaround would be great.

Comment: Hi man, found a solution on this ?

Comment: Have you managed to figure it out? We are seeing the exact same problem..